# Text selection in Android application using PhoneGap?

Tags: android, cordova

I'm developing Android app using PhoneGap, i tried to select a text by long pressing, by default long press is disabled on Android + Phonegap. Can you please suggest me any other workaround.

Thanks in advance - sri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joe is working on a fix for this issue. If you want to globally enable copy/paste in a PhoneGap app you should look at the following issue on GitHub.

https://github.com/callback/callback-android/pull/18

If you merge in the code in that pull request you will get the functionality you want. It's coming in a future release of PhoneGap.